# how to get the opposite color of any background images

Tags: delphi, image, color-picker

how to get the right color automatically that is depending on the background? if its darker background image, that will automatically change the font color into brighter colors.
was it possible? any idea?

Comment: and what is opposite to #808080 (gray) background?

Comment: +1 this is the classic trap for such a function

Comment: actually, its very dependant on perceptive model chosen, and which *linear* metric to use as "oppositeness"

Comment: @user205376 would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @David Heffernan: actually it is quite large, you will be bored, promise! :) What i meant: RGB colour denotes a vector in cartesian coordinates (0,0,0)->(R,G,B). It is convenient to view RGB colourspace as cube, however when it comes to perceptive models (as in perceiving an opposite colour), its worth to recall what weights of channels for the _human eye_ approximately are [0.299,0.587,0.114] (R,G,B channels respectively)

Comment: @user205376 That's not boring at all. How would you answer this question?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

David's answer is generally working very well. But there are a few options, and I will mention some of them. First, the very most naïve approach, is to do

```
function InvertColor(const Color: TColor): TColor;
begin
    result := TColor(Windows.RGB(255 - GetRValue(Color),
                                 255 - GetGValue(Color),
                                 255 - GetBValue(Color)));
end;
```

but this suffers from the #808080 problem (why?). A very nice solution is David's, but it looks very bad for some unfortunate background colours. Although the text is certainly visible, it looks horrible. One such "unfortunate" background colour is #008080.

Usually I prefer the text to be black if the background is "light", and white if the background is "dark". I thus do

```
function InvertColor(const Color: TColor): TColor;
begin
  if (GetRValue(Color) + GetGValue(Color) + GetBValue(Color)) > 384 then
    result := clBlack
  else
    result := clWhite;
end;
```

Also, if you are using Delphi 2009+ and targeting Windows Vista+, you might be interested in the `GlowSize` parameter of the `TLabel`.

Comment: @Andreas thing about my xorColor function is that I xor it with the background color so it's intent is a little different from your routine.

Comment: Well, the test is really just `[Red(C) + Green(C) + Blue(C)]/3 > 128` where 128 is halfway between 0 (absolute darkness) and 255 (full intensity).

Comment: the code works fine. but what if the background is images? how can we get the opposite of its background coz the pixel is not even?

Comment: Iterate over exery pixel, basically. Do you want each character to have the same colour, or should the colour of each character reflect the local average background colour? In any case, you just have to find the "average" colour under the character in question. I think the simlest way is to sum up the R, G, and B components of each pixel (that is, compute R_tot = R_pixel1 + R_pixel2 + ...) and similarly for G_tot and B_tot. Then find R_average = R_tot / num_pixels and similarly for G_average and B_average.

Comment: @Andreas you also need to get a call to ColorToRGB somewhere in here before you go poking around for RGB values.

Comment: @David: Yes. In most cases this isn't necessary, but you should always add it so that the unfortunate cases doesn't cause any bugs.

Comment: @Andreas score one to you, I just replaced my function with yours in my code base!  ;-)

Comment: clInfoBk, clHighLightText, clBtnHighLight, clBtnFace are some TColors where InvertColor returns clWhite for a (nearly) white background. In these cases ColorToRGB is necessary!

Comment: @johnny: Indeed, because these are not RGB values, but system colour values.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, yes. I just thought I'd give a heads up to anyone who adopts your function. Although they (might) understand the limitations of the function, their fellow programmers might not.

Answer (score 13):

I use the following to give me a color that contrasts the specified color:

```
function xorColor(BackgroundColor: TColor): TColor;
begin
  BackgroundColor := ColorToRGB(BackgroundColor);
  Result := RGB(
    IfThen(GetRValue(BackgroundColor)>$40, $00, $FF),
    IfThen(GetGValue(BackgroundColor)>$40, $00, $FF),
    IfThen(GetBValue(BackgroundColor)>$40, $00, $FF)
  );
end;
```

Comment: @user205376 you would typically set the Pen into xor mode with Pen.Mode := pmXor, set the color with Pen.Color := xorColor(backgroundColor) and then draw

Comment: ah, colour for subsequent xor as F(background-color), got it, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I try compute contrast based on "linear" color scheme, but it is really not good on pink and cyan color input values.
Much better it is calculate based on RGB formula:

```
brightness = sqrt( .241 * R^2 + .691 * G^2 + .068 * B^2 )
```

In Delphi i create this subroutine:

```
function GetContrastingColor(Color: TColor): TColor;
var r,g,b:double;i:integer;
begin
Color := ColorToRGB(Color);
r:=GetRValue(Color) ;
g:=GetGValue(Color) ;
b:=GetBValue(Color) ;
i:=round( Sqrt(
      r * r * 0.241 +
      g * g * 0.691 +
      b * b * 0.068));
if (i > 128) then   // treshold seems good in wide range
  Result := clBlack
else
  Result := clWhite;
end;
```

Comment: FWIW Ten Years On: This is superior to Andreas's routine above. I have tested both extensively. Both are good, but this delivers noticeably better results overall.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with D6, when the `TColor` was `clWindow`.  I discovered that if I did not first run `ColorToRGB(Color)`, `GetXValue(Color)` would report the R,G,B value of `clWindow` as 5,0,0 respectively.  Which is nearly black, while `clWindow` was defined as 255,255,255 on my test environment.  This seems to only be a problem for values sent in using the constant, if I sent in the hex or int equivalents it worked fine.

```
function InvertColor(const Color: TColor): TColor;
begin
  if (GetRValue(ColorToRGB(Color)) +
      GetGValue(ColorToRGB(Color)) +
      GetBValue(ColorToRGB(Color)))/3 > 128 then
    result := clBlack //color is light
  else
    result := clWhite; //color is dark
end;
```